# How is it possible that you can see connected clients of an WiFi without even connected with it?

Tags: network, router

Hey folks I have an small question about Network security.

I was playing around yesterday with airodump-ng and saw that I was able to see that my other laptop is connected to that WiFi but how is it possible?

```
BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames
"Router MAC"         "My Laptop MAC"
D4:60:E3:55:7D:2C  18:CF:5E:C2:70:C1  -21   0e- 0e    0      6895
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the MAC addresses are seeable in "clear text", or we should say clear waves.
Else how should the wifi router know the received frame is for him ?
See OSI Model. The encryption is in higher layers.